# I am having trouble with Sed

Tags: linux, string, replace, sed

I am trying to use the sed command to replace this line:

```
charmm.c36a4.20140107.newcali4.fixhcali.grange.b
```

with:

```
charmm.20140911.c36a4.3rd.ghost2.model3rd
```

When I use:

```
sed -i '/s/firstline/secondline/g'
```

It doesn't work. I think the periods are messing it up. How do I get around this?

Comment: what exactly your command? `-i` means you want to directly modify the file but i can't see any through your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed uses regular expressions, so `.` matches any character. If you want to only match the `.` character itself, tell sed to look for `\.`

so to change the first line into the second line:

```
sed -e 's/charmm\.c36a4.20140107\.newcali4\.fixhcali\.grange\.b/charmm.20140911.c36a4.3rd.ghost2.model3rd/g' < filetochange >newfile
```

Here, I added "g" so it does it globally, ie, if there are several instances on the same line, all will be changed. If you remove the "g", it will only change the first occurence on each line.

It reads from `filetochange` and writes to `newfile`

If you do :

```
sed -i -e 's/charmm\.c36a4.20140107\.newcali4\.fixhcali\.grange\.b/charmm.20140911.c36a4.3rd.ghost2.model3rd/g' filetochange
```

it will directly do the change in "filetochange" ... but please be careful, a badly written sed -i could mess up the file and make it unusable

Comment: Isn't `.` a character?

Comment: @hek2mgl: you can read about regular expressions in : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression  . It is a powerful thing, and many unix/linux commands use those (grep, sed, awk, etc). To answer the question, yes it is a character, so the regexp `.` will also match a character `.` , but it will also match any other character. So it's best to really say "I meant the character ." by using the regexp `\.` to match only that character

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you can omit escaping the dot since it *is* a character what makes the answer somewhat meaningless in this context.

Comment: @hek2mgl : if you want to replace all `.` into `-`, you use `sed -e 's/\./-/g'` ... If you used `sed -e 's/./-/g'` instead, it would turn **any** (here, every, because of the g option) characters (not just `.`) into as many `-` . But maybe if you are sure that there will be only "." at that place within that long string, then yes you could omit the backslashes because the "context" will help you not messing up other lines than the intended ones.

Comment: Sure, I know that. I meant *this question* with *context*

Answer (score -1):

The `s` command follows this syntax:

```
s/pattern/replacement/
```

You need to drop the `/` in front of the `sed` command.

Comment: That was a typo I did not have that slash when i tried the code

Comment: Yes, the period is indeed a special char. It means *"any character"*. However since the literal dot `.` **is** a character, it won't be a problem.

Comment: @FSUresearch: If you copy-and-paste the *exact* commands that you actually entered, you'll avoid typos -- and we'll have *some* chance of being able to help you. If we can't see the exact command, we can't help. Please update your question to make it clear what you're actually doing.